# Sylius-Standard admin panel : no css/js

Tags: php, npm, yarnpkg, sylius

I've installed the latest **Sylius-Standard** (based on Sylius 1.0@dev) and followed the quick tutorial. Everything is working fine *except* the admin panel, where CSS and JS return 500 when accessed in dev mode (via `app_dev.php`).

[image: demo]

I can see that they are fetched from a path that does not include `app_dev.php`. For instance, `app.js` is fetched from `http://my.local.domain/assets/admin/js/app.js`, which returns a 500 because it tries to access the prod database that is not setup.

There should be no need to create the prod database or install prod assets to access the admin panel in dev mode — what am I doing wrong?

Comment: put your .htaccess content

Comment: Well I haven't changed it from the Sylius-Standard repo, but I don't think that changes anything anyway

Comment: What kind of web server do you use?

Comment: I too am having this problem with a fresh install of sylius-standard. Tried gulp & assets:install

Comment: I had the same problem when i first installed it, i made an issue in github and they said it was fixed. I can't find my original issue though. You shouldn't need to run npm install but at this stage you do. Can you create another issue in the Syslius Standard repo - https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius-Standard

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sylius use a gulp library to manage css and js. The following command should fix your problem:

```
$ npm install
$ npm run gulp
```

**Edit**

After a few years, this is the proper answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59135635/4243630

Comment: Sylius, yes, but it is not required for Sylius-Standard, and was working in the previous versions. Besides, it should not call the prod database in dev

Comment: `yarn install` and `yarn build` sorts out that problem. Thanks for the hint. We are on Sylius 1.2.x

Answer (score 1):

In order to see a fully functional frontend you will need to install its assets.

Sylius uses Gulp to build frontend assets using Yarn as a JavaScript package manager.

Having Yarn installed, go to your project directory to install the dependencies:

```
$ yarn install

//Then build the frontend assets by running:

$ yarn build
```

We are on Sylius 1.2.x, we followed the official [documentation](https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.2/book/installation/installation.html#installing-assets)

This sorted out that problem for us.

If you are on 1.x [this is the link to the documentation](https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.0/book/installation/installation.html#installing-assets)

This should solve your problem.